# Tensor had NaN values - TensorFlow faster-rccn training error

Tags: python, tensorflow

This is the cmd output I get. It varies with how many steps it does before the error but is always less than 20.

```
C:\Users\edupt\Documents\GitHub\Project>python object_detection/train.py \ --logtostderr \ --train_dir=train \ --pipeline_config_path=faster_rcnn_resnet101.config
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\edupt\Documents\GitHub\Project\object_detection\trainer.py:176: create_global_step (from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.create_global_step
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\edupt\Documents\GitHub\Project\object_detection\core\preprocessor.py:1922: calling squeeze (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) with squeeze_dims is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use the `axis` argument instead
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\edupt\Documents\GitHub\Project\object_detection\core\box_predictor.py:371: calling reduce_mean (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) with keep_dims is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
keep_dims is deprecated, use keepdims instead
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\edupt\Documents\GitHub\Project\object_detection\core\losses.py:269: softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:

Future major versions of TensorFlow will allow gradients to flow
into the labels input on backprop by default.

See @{tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2}.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\edupt\Documents\GitHub\Project\object_detection\builders\optimizer_builder.py:105: get_or_create_global_step (from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.get_or_create_global_step
INFO:tensorflow:Summary name Learning Rate is illegal; using Learning_Rate instead.
INFO:tensorflow:Summary name /clone_loss is illegal; using clone_loss instead.
C:\Users\edupt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gradients_impl.py:100: UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.
  "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\edupt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\slim\python\slim\learning.py:737: Supervisor.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.training.supervisor) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession
2018-10-01 21:26:27.032708: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2018-10-01 21:26:27.350000: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1392] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.7085
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 6.00GiB freeMemory: 4.96GiB
2018-10-01 21:26:27.356938: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1471] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-10-01 21:26:29.297942: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:952] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-10-01 21:26:29.300781: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:958]      0
2018-10-01 21:26:29.302611: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:971] 0:   N
2018-10-01 21:26:29.305150: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1084] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 4726 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from train\model.ckpt-0
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Session.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoint to path train\model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Queues.
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 0.
INFO:tensorflow:global step 1: loss = 4.7042 (19.631 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 2: loss = 4.7257 (0.878 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 3: loss = 4.4725 (0.851 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 4: loss = 4.2467 (0.832 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 5: loss = 4.0482 (0.922 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 6: loss = 3.8669 (0.647 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 7: loss = 3.7094 (0.731 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 8: loss = 3.2892 (0.629 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 9: loss = 3.6964 (0.608 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError'>, LossTensor is inf or nan. : Tensor had NaN values
         [[Node: CheckNumerics = CheckNumerics[T=DT_FLOAT, message="LossTensor is inf or nan.", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](clone_loss/_3493)]]

Caused by op 'CheckNumerics', defined at:
  File "object_detection/train.py", line 198, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\edupt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "object_detection/train.py", line 194, in main
    worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir)
  File "C:\Users\edupt\Documents\GitHub\Project\object_detection\trainer.py", line 227, in train
    total_loss = tf.check_numerics(total_loss, 'LossTensor is inf or nan.')
  File "C:\Users\edupt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 968, in check_numerics
    "CheckNumerics", tensor=tensor, message=message, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\edupt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\edupt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3414, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\edupt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1740, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): LossTensor is inf or nan. : Tensor had NaN values
         [[Node: CheckNumerics = CheckNumerics[T=DT_FLOAT, message="LossTensor is inf or nan.", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](clone_loss/_3493)]]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\edupt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1322, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\edupt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1307, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\edupt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1409, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: LossTensor is inf or nan. : Tensor had NaN values
         [[Node: CheckNumerics = CheckNumerics[T=DT_FLOAT, message="LossTensor is inf or nan.", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](clone_loss/_3493)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/train.py", line 198, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\edupt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "object_detection/train.py", line 194, in main
    worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir)
  File "C:\Users\edupt\Documents\GitHub\Project\object_detection\trainer.py", line 296, in train
    saver=saver)
  File "C:\Users\edupt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\slim\python\slim\learning.py", line 770, in train
    sess, train_op, global_step, train_step_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\edupt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\slim\python\slim\learning.py", line 487, in train_step
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\edupt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 900, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\edupt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1135, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\edupt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1316, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\edupt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1335, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: LossTensor is inf or nan. : Tensor had NaN values
         [[Node: CheckNumerics = CheckNumerics[T=DT_FLOAT, message="LossTensor is inf or nan.", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](clone_loss/_3493)]]

Caused by op 'CheckNumerics', defined at:
  File "object_detection/train.py", line 198, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\edupt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "object_detection/train.py", line 194, in main
    worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir)
  File "C:\Users\edupt\Documents\GitHub\LEGO-ID-Project\object_detection\trainer.py", line 227, in train
    total_loss = tf.check_numerics(total_loss, 'LossTensor is inf or nan.')
  File "C:\Users\edupt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 968, in check_numerics
    "CheckNumerics", tensor=tensor, message=message, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\edupt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\edupt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3414, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\edupt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1740, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): LossTensor is inf or nan. : Tensor had NaN values
         [[Node: CheckNumerics = CheckNumerics[T=DT_FLOAT, message="LossTensor is inf or nan.", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](clone_loss/_3493)]]
```

I have tried reducing the learning rate and increasing the batch size but this doesn't help. I don't think it is my annotations as I have error checking with those. I have tried a lot of the other stuff that people with similar errors get with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was my annotations after all. This became clear when I noticed it crashing on the same step but changing this position when I would recreate the random ordered TF Record files.

The error with was with some of my annotaiton files having the Maximums and Minimums the wrong way around.

Comment: `The error with was with some of my annotation files having the Maximums and Minimums the wrong way around.`

Can you please elaborate more on this?

Answer (score 2):

I just seen this as i had the same issue. I changed my generate_tfrecord.py with these changes:

```
for index, row in group.object.iterrows():
        if (row['xmin'] / width) >= (row['xmax'] / width):
            pass
        elif (row['ymin'] / height) >= (row['ymax'] / height):
            pass
        else:
            xmins.append(row['xmin'] / width)
            xmaxs.append(row['xmax'] / width)
            ymins.append(row['ymin'] / height)
            ymaxs.append(row['ymax'] / height)
            classes_text.append(row['class'].encode('utf8'))
            classes.append(class_text_to_int(row['class']))
```

This essentially will save you a lot of time if you have a large set of annotations to go through. I hope this helps someone.